Outlook Crash in Legacy Mac UI with inline attachments and AttachmentsChanged event handler in taskpane
Issue: Outlook client crashes when sending a mail with inline attachment while task pane add-in has Office.EventType.AttachmentsChanged event handler attached to it.
Repro steps (Step by Step):
Deploy an xml outlook officejs add-in which has an event handler for attachments changed in taskpane.
Draft a mail with at least 1 inline attachment.
Invoke taskpane add-in. Make sure Attachments Changed event handler is running in background.
Click on the send button.
Expected Behavior: Mails should be sent successfully. Outlook client should not crash.
Actual Behavior: Outlook crashes when the send button is clicked.
Sample code (script lab yaml):
name: Blank snippet
description: Create a new snippet from a blank template.
host: OUTLOOK
api_set: {}
script:
  content: |
    $("#run").on("click", run);
 
    function run() {
      Office.context.mailbox.item.addHandlerAsync(Office.EventType.AttachmentsChanged, (val) => { console.log("recieved event::", JSON.stringify(val)); }, () => { console.log("added handler successfully");});
    }
  language: typescript
template:
  content: |
    <button id="run" class="ms-Button"><span class="ms-Button-label">Run</span></button>
  language: html
style:
  content: |-
    section.samples {
        margin-top: 20px;
    }
 
    section.samples .ms-Button, section.setup .ms-Button {
        display: block;
        margin-bottom: 5px;
        margin-left: 20px;
        min-width: 80px;
    }
  language: css
libraries: |
  https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/lib/1.1/hosted/office.js
  @types/office-js
  office-ui-fabric-core@11.1.0/dist/css/fabric.min.css
  office-ui-fabric-js@1.5.0/dist/css/fabric.components.min.css
  core-js@2.4.1/client/core.min.js
  @types/core-js
  jquery@3.1.1
  @types/jquery@3.3.1

We tried to send a mail with taskpane add-in running with AttachmentsChanged event handler of OfficeJS API. We were hoping to send the email without crash and keep log of attachments in console.
